# What is the best way to update an application on a raspberry without the internet?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I have a suite of applications on my raspberry that works without the internet. I would like, when the raspberry is connected to the internet, to update the application (mysql, laravel files and vuejs files). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I can's see that this is Pi specific.  Define "the best way".  You seem to be asking for opinions which is also off topic.

Comment: Your question seems trite, but perhaps I've missed something. Why don't you run `sudo apt upddate && sudo apt upgrade` when you're connected to the Internet?

Comment: I don't want to update raspberry pi os but my application in bluetooth, or something else. I have never done a web application update with an automatic file update (laravel, mysql, vuejs) with a shell script for example...